# How to generate files based on puppet array contents?

Tags: puppet

I'd like to be able to create files based on the contents of an array.  Here is what I have tried:

```
class make_files (
    $servers = ['server-1','server-2','server-3'],
) {
    file { $servers :
        path    => '/tmp',
        content => $servers,
    }
}
```

... but when I execute this like so ...

```
# puppet apply --modulepath=/root/modules -e 'include make_files'
```

... I get this output:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for host-001 in environment production in 0.13 seconds
Error: Cannot alias File[server-2] to ["/tmp"] at /root/modules/make_files/manifests/init.pp:9; resource ["File", "/tmp"] already declared at /root/modules/make_files/manifests/init.pp:9
```

I was hoping to have three files ...

```
# ls /tmp/server-?
/tmp/server-1  /tmp/server-2  /tmp/server-3
# cat /tmp/server-?
server-1
server-2
server-3
```

It would really be cool if someone could tell me how to get the files to be named: server-1.cfg, server-2.cfg and server-3.cfg.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you already defined resource `File['/tmp']`, in `init.pp` file.
This is the main cause of the problem you got:

> Error: Cannot alias File[server-2] to ["/tmp"] at /root/modules/make_files/manifests/init.pp:9; resource ["File", "/tmp"] already declared at /root/modules/make_files/manifests/init.pp:9

Please check the meaning of the [path](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-path) attribute. Maybe this will clarify the problem.
Create

```
$files_to_create = ['/path/server-1','/path/server-2','/path/server-3']
```

and then use it:

```
    file { $files_to_create :
        content => $servers,
    }
```

Please also be sure that `/path` directory  already exist in the filesystem. So far puppet is not able to create intermediate directories.